# Importing huge table exhausts UNDO extents in Oracle RDS (ORA-01628)

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, amazon-rds, rollback, datapump

I'm attempting to do an impdp on RDS, Oracle 12c. I'm importing only one table for this particular impdp job but every time I try to import it, UNDO usage gets to about 50% and then the logs just say `Resumable error: ORA-01628: max # extents (32765) reached for rollback segment`.

Since this is RDS I cannot manually manage undo. I created a fresh RDS instance with a new 4TB UNDO tablespace to perform the import of just this table. I've read about creating one giant rollback segment and also about creating lots of small rollback segments to solve this problem. I've also read I can split the import into multiple parts, but I'd rather not do that if possible. Is there anything more I can do here to maybe stop the UNDO tablespace from running out of extents?

Comment: Direct path load, skip index. Im concern about a Rollback error instead of UNDO error. Two different technologies,  two different errors, two different solutions. (IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

[IF: ORA-1628 Reported During Import (Doc ID 1955310.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1955310.1)

- Skip indexes and statistics
- If the table already exists, drop it or use `table_exists_action=replace`.
- use `CONTENT=ALL` instead of `DATA_ONLY` (redundant with previous point)